# get запрос на несуществующий домен, зная IP

Tags: php

Предположим, на хостинге есть сайт с привязанным доменом, домен владелец не проплатил, поэтому регистратор его удалил. Но зная IP хостинга и прописав запись себе в hosts, можно спокойно ввести домен в адресную строку и сёрфить по тому сайту.
Как в php можно выполнить get-запрос, чтобы отправить его на известный IP-адрес, но передать требуемый мне домен (не меняя глобально hosts) и получить содержимое сайта именно на этом настроенном домене?

Передать его в заголовке host?

Comment: Причём тут пых? Почитайте про DNS

Comment: @mpakfm при том, что код пишу на пыхе и возможно есть какое-то более изящное решение, чем пилить на сокетах

Comment: Не шарю в пыхе, но что то вроде `file_get_content("http(s)://127.0.0.1")`? Не?

Comment: @icYFTL ну и откроет /var/www/, а нужно, чтобы хостинг в ответ на запрос отдал файлы с VirtualHost нужного передаваемого домена

Comment: @Robert, тогда скушно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот такой вариант должен работать, только что проверил:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init('1.2.3.4');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Host: example.com']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
echo curl_exec($ch);
```

Источник: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9932914/5698975

Comment: То, что доктор прописал. Спасибо!

Comment: К глубокому сожалению, всё ещё актуально :( я сам себя наколол, забыв, что домен, на котором тестирую, прописан у меня в хостс и пыха тоже стоит на этом же компьютере :( убрал, сделал flush dns и не работает :(

Comment: Странно, у меня работало: 1. Я на хостинге привязал домен, который 100% занят другим сайтом; 2. Написал код как в ответе - запрос обработался правильно

Comment: возможно какая-то проблема из-за поверки сертификата. В любом случае ваш ответ предельно близок. Сделал то же самое, но через заголовки с file_get_contents (а то расширение сокетов и cURL много где не работает).
Огромное спасибо за помощь :)

Answer (score 0):

Прописывая домен под IP себе в hosts вы всего-навсего сообщаете своей системе что ей не нужно делать DNS запрос, а брать готовый IP адрес из этого файла и на него слать запрос. По сути это ничем не отличается от обычного запроса на этот адрес в браузере и идентичен запросу на этот домен.

Доступ к VirtualHosts на сервере вы точно так не получите так как, если бы посмотрели как он работает в большинстве случаев (порт на виртуальный домен, **внутренний** IP адрес на домен), вы, проставив внешний IP адрес у себя не сможете узнать на какой внутренний IP адрес он будет выходить.

Смотрите примеры ответов на [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/719672/how-to-send-an-http-request-for-a-certain-domain-name-to-a-specific-ip-address) о том, как отослать запрос на IP адрес с нужным вам доменным именем.

**PS** читая эти ответы понимаю, что «костыль» автора вопроса имеет место быть ;)